# How to Fix an array and a loop?

Tags: c#

I created a User login and password program where a user has to type in a username and a password. I have my usernames and passwords in parallel arrays. If a user types the username or password wrong for the first time they get a message saying "Username is incorrect try again" or "password is incorrect try again".

My problem is if the user types in the wrong username for the first time they get the error message, but if the user type in the right username for the second time they still get the error message.

What I found out is when they get it wrong for the first time the program asks them to input the second username instead of the first one. How can I fix this so the program lets the user type in the first username instead of asking for the second username?

```
// The available usernames and passwords a user can input
string[] username = {"BUL","GVL","UDF","RFT","WDR" };
int[] password = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
Console.WriteLine("\nUsername,Password \nBUL,100 \nGVL,200 \nUDF,300 \nRFT,400 \nWDR,500 ");
// Loop for Username Input
for (int i = 0; i < username.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Username");
    string inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();
    // if user type a wrong username, they need to try again
    if (username[i] != inputUsername)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Username, Try again");
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Where the part in your code that asks the user to reenter his username if he entered it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool isUserNameValid = false;
string inputUsername = "";
do
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter Username");
  inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();
  for ( int i = 0; i < username.Length; i++ )
    if ( username[i] == inputUsername )
    {
      isUserNameValid = true;
      break;
    }
  if ( !isUserNameValid )
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Username, Try again");
}
while ( !isUserNameValid );

bool isPasswordValid = false;
int inputPassword = 0;
do
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
  int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inputPassword);
  for ( int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++ )
    if ( password[i] == inputPassword )
    {
      isPasswordValid = true;
      break;
    }
  if ( !isPasswordValid )
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password, Try again");
}
while ( !isPasswordValid );
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) to store the usernames and passwords as [Key-Value-Pairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1) instead of storing theme in two separate arrays? This way, you can check both username and password in one step.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "BUL", "100" },
    { "GVL", "200" },
    { "UDF", "300" },
    { "RFT", "400" },
    { "WDR", "500" }
};

while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Username");
    string inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
    string pass = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!dic.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(inputUsername, pass)))
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Username/password, Try again");
    else  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist using `Array`, then you could do as the following code. But it would be always better to use `Dictionaries` in this scenario, which provides you a mapping between UserName and Password. If you were to use Arrays, you would need to map them yourself based on Array Index.

You can employ two loops, each validating the username and then combination of username/password until it is valid.

```
string inputUserName,inputPassword;
// Loop for Username Input
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Username");
    inputUserName = Console.ReadLine();
    if(username.Contains(inputUserName))
        break;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect UserName");
}
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
    inputPassword = Console.ReadLine();
    var indexOfUserName = Array.IndexOf(username,inputUserName);
    if(Int32.TryParse(inputPassword,out var value) && password[indexOfUserName] == value)
        break;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Password");
}
```

While using Dictionary you could change the code as follows.

```
// Dictionary declaration
var userDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>
{
    { "BUL", 100 },
    { "GVL", 200 },
    { "UDF", 300 },
    { "RFT", 400 },
    { "WDR", 500 }
};


string inputUserName,inputPassword;
// Loop for Username Input
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Username");
    inputUserName = Console.ReadLine();
    if(userDictionary.Keys.Contains(inputUserName))
        break;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect UserName");
}
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
    inputPassword = Console.ReadLine();
    if(Int32.TryParse(inputPassword,out var value) && userDictionary[inputUserName] == value)
        break;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect UserName");
}
```

If you would like to further eliminate some duplicate code, you could refactor the code as following.

```
var userDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>
{
    { "BUL", 100 },
    { "GVL", 200 },
    { "UDF", 300 },
    { "RFT", 400 },
    { "WDR", 500 }
};

Console.WriteLine("\nUsername,Password \nBUL,100 \nGVL,200 \nUDF,300 \nRFT,400 \nWDR,500 ");
var userName = ReadFromUserTillTrue("Enter UserName","Incorrect UserName",x=>userDictionary.Keys.Contains(x));
var password = ReadFromUserTillTrue("Enter Password","Incorrect Password",x=>Int32.TryParse(x,out var value) && userDictionary[userName]== value);
```

Where `ReadFromUserTillTrue`is defined as

```
public string ReadFromUserTillTrue(string promptMessage,string errorMessage,Func<string,bool> validator)
{
    var input = string.Empty;
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(promptMessage);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if(validator(input))
            break;
        else
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides realy great answers in this thread, I'd also recommend to check [Polly.NET](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) framework. When I need to do something with retries I find it already has something that serves my needs. Below is an example of how you can implement retries with countdown (and there is many more other nice things in the framework):

```
var usernames = new List<string>(){ "BUL", "GVL", "UDF", "RFT", "WDR" };
int[] passwords = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };

var user = Policy
    .HandleResult<String>(r => !usernames.Contains(r))
    .RetryForever((r)=> Console.WriteLine($"Username is incorrect, Try again"))
    .Execute(() => {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Username:");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    });

var expectedPassword = passwords[usernames.IndexOf(user)];
var maxRetries = 5;

Policy
    .HandleResult<int>(r => r != expectedPassword)
    .Retry(maxRetries, (r, i) => Console.WriteLine($"Password is incorrect. Retries left: {maxRetries - i + 1}"))
    .Execute(() => {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password:");
        // should here also be a retry? try do that with Polly :)
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),  out var password);
        return password;
    });
```